# Where does getRequestDispatcher("path") look?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Using embedded tomcat, this code:

```
System.out.println("getServletPath: " + request.getServletPath());
System.out.println("getServletContext: " + request.getServletContext().getContextPath());
System.out.println("getServerName: " + request.getServerName());
System.out.println("getServerPort: " + request.getServerPort());
```

Prints out:

```
getServletPath: /example
getServletContext: 
getServerName: localhost
getServerPort: 9090
```

Does that mean that:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/example/read.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Will look at this URL to `forward(request, response)` to the JSP:

`http://localhost:9090/example/read.jsp`?

Is there a way to print out what **absolute** URL `getRequestDispatcher("relativePath")` is addressing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) explains this

> The `getRequestDispatcher` method takes a `String` argument describing a
>   path  within the scope of the ServletContext. **This path must be
>   relative to the root of the  ServletContext and begin with a ‘/’, or
>   be empty**. The method uses the path to  look up a servlet, **using the
>   servlet path matching rules in Chapter 12, “Mapping  Requests to
>   Servlets”,** wraps it with a RequestDispatcher object, and returns the 
>   resulting object. If no servlet can be resolved based on the given
>   path, a  RequestDispatcher is provided that returns the content for
>   that path.

Those rules are the following

> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path  of the servlet. A successful match selects the
>      servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done  by stepping down the path tree a directory
>      at a time, using the ’/’ character as a  path separator. The longest
>      match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet  container will try to match a servlet that handles
>      requests for the extension. An  extension is defined as the part of
>      the last segment after the last ’.’ character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will  attempt to serve content appropriate for the
>      resource requested. If a "default"  servlet is defined for the
>      application, it will be used. Many containers provide an  implicit
>      default servlet for serving content.

You ask

> Does that mean that:
>
> request.getRequestDispatcher("/example/display.jsp").forward(request,
>   response); Will look at this URL to forward(request, response) to the
>   JSP:
>
> `http://localhost:9090/example/display.jsp`?

No, it doesn't send an HTTP request, so the path has nothing to do with a URI. It's more of an internal path that the Servlet container will try to match with its various url-mappings for Servlets.

You also ask

> Is there a way to print out what absolute URL getRequestDispatcher("relativePath") is addressing?

No. And it isn't exactly an absolute URL. It's a path that can be handled by some resource in the web application context.

---

After your edit, you `addWebapp` to your `Tomcat` instance.

```
tomcat.addWebapp(null, "/view2/example2", new File("src/com/example/view/example").getAbsolutePath());
```

You then send a request to

```
 /view2/example2/read.jsp
```

I'm going to assume that `read.jsp` is in

```
src/com/example/view/example/
```

I believe it's in the publicly accessible part of the web application and therefore the Servlet container can render it and respond with it.

You've also added a webapp with `addContext` which seems to be similar to `addWebapp`

```
context = tomcat.addContext("", base.getAbsolutePath());
```

and added servlet mappings to *this* context.

```
Tomcat.addServlet(context, "example", new ExampleController());
context.addServletMapping("/example/*", "example");
```

**I was wrong about the `/example/*` not being able to handle `/example`.**

When you send a request to

```
/example
```

since the context path is "", the `Context` above will be used and the mapping will match the `ExampleController` registered above. Your `Servlet` code will execute and reach

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/view2/example2/read.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Note the javadoc of [`ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29)

> The pathname specified may be relative, although it cannot extend
>   outside the current servlet context.

In other words, this `Servlet`, `ExampleController` was registered in the `ServletContext` mapped to the context path `""`, ie. root. The path `/view2/example2/read.jsp` is referring to another context. Since this context doesn't have a mapping for it, it responds with 404.

You can get a reference to another web applications in a different context. You have to use [`ServletContext#getContext(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29). For example

```
 ServletContext otherContext = request.getServletContext().getContext("/view2/example2");
```

Now that you have the `ServletContext`, you can get a `RequestDispatcher` for a resource in *that* context.

```
otherContext.getRequestDispatcher("/read.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

since [`ServletContext#getRequestDispatcher(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) states

> The pathname must begin with a / and is interpreted as relative to the current context root.

---

**Final Answer:**

`getRequestDispatcher("path")` will look at the directory set in the `addWebapp` method when referencing a JSP file. If a blank page or `NullPointerException` is displayed, ensure that you have done the following:

1. Remove all the `addWebapp` definitions.
2. Run `addContext` then `addWebApp` like this so they both point to `ROOT`:

`File base = new File("src/com/example/view"); 
context = tomcat.addContext("", base.getAbsolutePath()); 
tomcat.addWebapp(null, "/", base.getAbsolutePath());`

1. In the servlet point to the jsp using `request.getRequestDispatcher("/example/read.jsp").forward(request, response);` provided that the directory /example exists in `"src/com/example/view"`.