# forward request from servlet to jsp after login using tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to forward request to a jsp file after login using tomacat. But it (servlet) does not forwarding the request. Can anyone figure it out the error here ?

Servlet :

```
public class AuthenticationServer extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doService(request, response);
    }

    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doService (request, response);
    }

    public void doService (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String user = request.getRemoteUser();
        request.setAttribute("user", user);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/" + request.getParameter("direct"));
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

When I printed the `"/" + request.getParameter("direct")`, it prints out `/welcome.jsp`. But it just don't forwards it.

Comment: Do your `servlet` and `JSP` belong to the same web app?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(String path);
```

The path specified may be relative, although it cannot extend outside the current servlet context. If the path begins with a **"/"** it is interpreted as relative to the current context root. If the servlet container cannot return a RequestDispatcher also this method returns `null`.Try this:`RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getParameter("direct"));`

Answer (score 1):

If you could specify the error it will make it easier to solve your problem...

The problem could be because it cannot find the jsp view. 
When you put a "/" in getRequestDispatcher() the path is relative to the root of your application. if http://localhost:8080 is your root  then your url will be http://localhost:8080/YourApp/welcome.jsp

you can get a more explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997130/where-does-getrequestdispatcherpath-look)